# Send / Receive MPI-Fortran-Java

Tags: java, fortran, mpi, openmpi

I have a send / receive implementation in Open-MPI and Java. The goal is to send a Fortran character set to Java. When Java receives this String it prints the following result.
[Result send/receive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/443eE.png)

My Fortran code is:

```
program simple4 
  implicit none 
  include 'mpif.h' 

  integer ierr,my_rank,size 
  integer src, dest, tag, position, charSize 
  integer status(MPI_STATUS_SIZE) 
  CHARACTER*80 TEXT

  call mpi_init(ierr) 
  call mpi_comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,my_rank,ierr) 
  call mpi_comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,size,ierr) 

  src = 0 
  dest = 1 
  tag = 999

  if(my_rank.eq.0) then
    position = 0 
    TEXT = "PRO" 
    call MPI_SEND(TEXT, 3, MPI_CHARACTER, dest, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr) 
  else 
    print *, "Fortran process ", my_rank
  end if 

  call mpi_finalize(ierr)

end
```

My Java code is:

```
....
char[] textChar = new char[3];
MPI.COMM_WORLD.recv(textChar, 3, MPI.CHAR, sourceRank, messageTag);
String text = String.copyValueOf(textChar);
System.out.println("Java - Text receive: " + text);
```

What would be the problem in my code?
Fortran and Java will not be able to communicate this way? What would be another solution?

Answer (score 1):

The root cause is a Fortran `CHARACTER` is in `ASCII` whereas a Java `String` is in `Unicode`, so some extra steps are involved.

Here is a snippet of what you could do in Java

```
byte[] textByte = new byte[3];
MPI.COMM_WORLD.recv(textByte, 3, MPI.BYTE, sourceRank, messageTag);
String text = new String(textByte, java.nio.charset.Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
System.out.println("Java - Text receive: " + text);
```

Comment: By default Fortran characters are ASCII, but several of the widely-used Fortran compilers also support Unicode as a non-default character kind.  That might point towards using Unicode on both sides of the communication, though I'm not sure how well MPI plays with Unicode.

Comment: good point ! I guess `MPI_INTEGER2` would be the Fortran datatype to be used, but what about Java ?